# Eclipse hangs after installing egit

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, egit, eclipse-ecf

I am using Eclipse Indigo. Today I tried to install egit plugin using link "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo".

While installing the egit, my proxy got squished and the install was stuck. I then logged in from a different proxy. The thing got installed.

Now when i am trying to start it again, i get this error "Accessing non-adaptable element org.eclipse.ecf.examples.remoteservices.hello.ds.host" and eclipse stops.

It does not show any error message or anything.

How should I solve this issue ?? 
Should i reset the eclipse proxy setting to a new location  without starting the IDE ??
Or should I reset eclipse to a point before installing egit 
 ??

Please explain the procedure in the answer.

Comment: I tried removing all entries from eclipse.ini. where are the proxy settings stored for eclipse ??

Comment: Also, "configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.core.net.prefs" file contains the proxy-host but no information on proxy login.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is really a proxy issue. Try launching eclipse after your network adapter is disconnected (unplug your lan/switch of wifi) This should put git in offline mode and you should be able to change your settings. We had tried this when we had issue with our versioning tool (perforce) and i am assuming git also works in a similar mode.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Eclipse from OS completely.
Additional: Remove the directories in /home/username/.eclipse. 
Everything!

Check for any eclipse executables using "locate eclipse" command in terminal.

Re-install the Eclipse Package using "sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform".
Your Eclipse will work fine. Check for the

Comment: reinstalling everything seems to be an obvious solution. Can you tell me your answer again.

Comment: no man. searched and searched. No other way. Atleast for me. :(